# How to select the USB mic & cam with Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: python-2.7, usb, selenium-chromedriver, microphone

Working on **Ubuntu 14.04**

Using **Python** w/ **Selenium Chrome Driver**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

then

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests')
options.add_argument('--disable-user-media-security=true')
options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

from there, I'd like to be able to choose the USB camera and the USB microphone.

May be there is a simpler way. If I could force Chromium to always use those USB devices by default, that's even better.

### lsusb

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 0c76:160a JMTek, LLC. <=== mic to use by default
Bus 002 Device 017: ID 05a3:9230 ARC International <=== cam to use by default
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 03eb:2ff8 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
```

Comment: What do you mean choose them? Do you mean select which of multiple devices are active?

Comment: I see that you are picking on my english, please don't, this is not my native language. I'd like to **select** my USB cam and USB mic, making sure that it's not using another device. I guess select from the active devices could work for me.

Comment: I'm not picking on your English, just trying to clarify what you're actually asking. It may not be your native language but it's the language in which this web site operates, and if I as a native speaker can't understand what you're asking, how can those users with other native languages be expected to?

Comment: I deeply apologize ... do you need more clarifications? ready to help?

Comment: @zabumba did you ever find a solution?